# "The types of vacations" vs " types of vacations"

Tags: articles

Here is a sentence that I get mixed up. This is the beginning of the paragraph. There's nothing before this sentence.

> 'The types' of vacations that people take nowadays are very different from vacations taken in years gone by.

I think the the reason 'the types'(definite article) is used in the first part is to differenciate the types that exist nowadays and the types that used to be in years gone by. If that is the case, I have no idea why 'the' is omissed in second vacations.

Then, any differences were made if I put it like  the following?

> 'The types' of vacations that people take nowadays are very different from **the types** of vacations taken in years gone by.

Comment: Then, any differences were made if I put it like  the following @oerkelens

Comment: Your addition of _types_ does make the parallel complete. In the original, indeed, _types_ are compared to _vacations_, which, from a puristic point of view, is indeed incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The*<sup>(1)</sup> types of vacations that people take nowadays are very different from vacations<sup>(2)</sup> taken in years gone by.

<sup>(1)</sup> The specific types of vacations that I am going to talk about, not types in general.

<sup>(2)</sup> Any, really any vacations that people took in the past. Not specified, all and any of them. *That* is how different the vacations are nowadays. Not just different from *the* vacations in the 1960's, but different from anything we've seen before.